# PowerPoint Slideshow shows only part of a slide

Tags: vba, vsto, slideshow, powerpoint

I have a weird problem with PowerPoint 2010:

I use the following code to remove all animations from a slide. This is done during slideshow:

```
  for (int i = slide.TimeLine.InteractiveSequences.Count; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                Sequence sequence = slide.TimeLine.InteractiveSequences[i];
                for (int x = sequence.Count; x >= 1; x--)
                {
                    sequence[x].Delete();
                }
            }

            for (int i = slide.TimeLine.MainSequence.Count; i >= 1; i--)
            {                                        
                slide.TimeLine.MainSequence[i].Delete();                    
            }    
        }
```

In one slide, which has a Picture and a TextBox and both use the MainSequence animation, after the animations are removed, the Slide appears in the slideshow with only the text but not the picture.

In another slide, after animations are removed, the textbox and the picture are both shown, but are drawn only half down - it really looks as if somebody took a rubber and wiped the bottom parts out! Very weird.

Here's an example screenshot. Notice the image on the right of the slide, which has its bottom half wiped off:
[image]

Redrawing the slides by using View.GotoSlide does not fix this. Adding an extra shape to the slides before/after removing the animations, does not help either.

When I create PNG thumbnails of these weird slides, the thumbnails look fine and contain all the shapes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This type of redraw bug has come up before.  After changing the visibility of shapes (or in this case, the animations) try moving them off the slide then back on again.  That seems to help in some case.

Comment: Thanks, but it dodn't work. Tried after removing the animation to move the shapes off the slide and back. Didn't help...

Comment: Did you also try a .View.GoToSlide(your slide's index) after moving the shape off and back?   And it might be worth trying this on a differently configured PC to see if it's a graphics card issue.  Come to think of it, try it on your dev PC but start the slide show with graphics acceleration disabled.

Comment: Thanks. I already tried the GoToSlide but it didn't help. Interesting that even going to another slide and coming back didn't change the slide's distorted look. Will try the Graphic-acceleration thing.